# Is it possible to override the UserHostAddress property of the HttpRequest class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, proxy-server

I have a situation where I need to put my application behind a proxy server,  this causes all the request's that are coming to my application to have the same set of IP addresses used by the proxy servers. However the Proxy server provides the real IP address  of the requestor in a custom header, that I can use through my application so I can know the real IP address of the requestor. This is mainly used for logging and tracking. Is there a way I can have the UserHostAddress property return the value from this custom header? This would save a lot of work, because this property referenced about a few hundred time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to change the behavior of the UserHostAddress property, however what you can do is add an extension method to the Request class (something like GetRealUserHostAddress()) and just do a global replace on UserHostAddress -> GetRealUserHostAddress() to rapidly sort out all the instances of it in your solution.

```
public static string GetRealUserHostAddress(this HttpRequestBase request)
{
    return request.Headers["HeaderName"] ?? request.UserHostAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that the proxy returns the real ip address of the client making the request, you don't need to use the `UserHostAddress` to read it; you can simply read the header directly:

```
string realIP = HttpContext.Request.Headers["actual_header_key"];
```

Comment: Yes, But then I will need to change exsiting code that already looking at the UserHostAddress property.

Comment: @user1449487 Then it's something the reverse proxy has to do for you. Check the documentation but I *really* doubt that there's any setting for this. Reverse proxies offer this extra header precisely for this purpose.

Comment: Ok let me check that out. If you can think of anything else please let me know.

Comment: I was doing some research on the reverse proxy I don't think is going to solve my issue either , I noticed that the DOT.NET framework is pulling the IP address of the client from the GetRemoteAddress() method on the HttpWorkerRequest Class. I did some digging and I found that this method  the GetRemoteAddress method retrieves the remote interface address of the client that issued the request and returns a pointer to a SOCKADDR structure. I am not really sure what this structure is, but I think in the case of the reverse proxy I will get that IP as well.

Comment: @user1449487 you are probably right, but reverse proxies will definitely expose the real client's IP address on one of the request headers. These header is usually called `X-Forwarded-For` but it may vary depending on the product.

Comment: yes I did some reading on it and it will, but I would still need to change my code wherever am referencing UserHostAddress. Times like these I wish I had used a wrapper object for that property.   Hey appreciated the suggestion thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You can read the custom header and place in the request context and use that later.